# How to give star rating on click of elements that are coming dynamically?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

The data shown here is coming dynamically. Now, the issue is that, I want to submit star ratings for each element. But when I click on a single element, the star rating is shown on all the elements as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9Ajz.png).

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 52px;">
  <div *ngFor="let i of imagedata;let j = index;" class="col-4">
    <div class="imgstyle" id=i+{{star}}>
      <!-- <mat-icon class="cookingpot2"> <img src="../../assets/cooking-pot 1.png"> -->
      <img (click)="onclick(j)" class="cookingpot1" src="{{i.HobbyIcon}}">
      <!-- </mat-icon> -->
    </div>
    <p style="margin-top: 10px;" class="imgcontent">{{i.HobbyName}}</p>
    <div id="star">
      <ul class="list-inline rating-list" *ngFor="let star of stars; let i= index">
        <li (click)="countStar(star)" [ngClass]="{'selected': (star <= selectedValue)}" (mouseover)="addClass(star)" (mouseout)="removeClass()"> <span class="material-icons">star</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div *ngIf="showMyContainer">
    <ul class="list-inline rating-list" *ngFor="let star of stars; let i= index">
      <li (click)="countStar(star)" [ngClass]="{'selected': (star <= selectedValue)}" (mouseover)="addClass(star)" (mouseout)="removeClass()"> <span class="material-icons">star</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: you need an array of "selectedValue", (declare selectedValue:number[] and use selectedValues[j], in the "click" pass also the variable "j" to cahnge the value of the element of the array) not a single variable. futhermore you has "repeat" two "i", the variable when loop over the image data and the i when you show the stars.